# XProtect support currently under Catalina

Tags: macos, anti-virus

From what I know, Catalina does not appear to be getting many updates?

Is XProtect updated in the background on Catalina, or is it now out of date?

If it is out of date now, would a virus/malware scanner, even a free one, mitigate associated risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2026) and XProtect was updated recently.  The last entries in the output of `system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType` are:

```
XProtectPlistConfigData:

  Version: 2168
  Source: Apple
  Install Date: 6/23/23, 12:41

XProtectPayloads:

  Version: 101
  Source: Apple
  Install Date: 6/23/23, 12:41
```

Comment: `softwareupdate --his -a --include-config-data` also gives this data, in a different format.

Comment: I run command under 10.15.7, my XProtectPlistConfigData is date 6/25/20

Comment: @paulj, Try `softwareupdate -l -a --include-config-data` to see what is available.

Comment: it lists macOSInstallerNotification, MRTConfigData, XProtectPlistConfigData, XProtectPayloads. Installing from command line softwareupdate -ia --include-config-data will only update these listed files

Answer (score 3):

#### XProtect will be updated as longs as it's compatible

There is an excellent writeup from the [Eclectic Light Company](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/09/22/how-long-does-apple-support-macos/) that addresses this:

> ... **the only support it receives are periodic updates to its security tools such as XProtect and MRT, which continue for as long as they remain compatible with that version of macOS**. Currently, that extends back to El Capitan, if not before.

This is based on observation as (stated in the article) is not published "officially" by Apple. This mirrors what Microsoft does with respect to [Defender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/msda-updates-previous-versions-technical-upgrade-support?view=o365-worldwide). Security updates for Defender are supplied so long as they are compatible with the (Defender) *engine*, not the version of Windows being run.